# Please explain this flatbed microwave design

Tags: electromagnetism, microwaves

Here is a Galantz flatbed microwave
[image: fifth]
The waveguide is smaller than a wavelength.

1)Usually apertures of less than a wavelength are considered to block EM wave but not here, why ?

2)The width of the waveguide is 6 cm and the height about 2 cm, does that polarize the EM waves alonf the 6cm axis  ?

Here's the inside of the oven :
[image: first image]
3)What's the purpose of that metal bulge in front of the magnetron output ?

Here's the bottom of the oven, the ceramic plate is lifted to reveal the wave stirrer
[image: second image]
The wave stirrer is removed to show the opening for the waves entry and the shaft of the stirring plate
[image: thid miage]

4) can you explain the geometry of the disk and the reason designers chose to make the waves enter the oven from below the stirring disk?
[image: fourth imge]